# Removing left recursion grammar using DCG

Tags: recursion, prolog, grammar, dcg

The following Grammar has left-recursion

**Grammar :**

```
Expr ::= E1|E2|E3|E4|E5|E6|E7

E1 ::= "(" Expr ")"
E2 ::= "not""(" Expr ")"
E3 ::= Expr "=>" Expr
E4 ::= Expr "=/=" Expr
E5 ::= Expr "*" Expr
E6 ::= Func "=>" Func
Func ::= Ter  (Ters)+","
...
```

and I'm trying to remove the LR in this manner ;

```
Expr ::= E1|...

E1 ::= Expr "*" Expr ==>   E1   ::= Expr Expr'
                           Expr'::= *Expr Expr'
```

but the problem still exists, How to fix it to get this program working?

**example query and test**

```
| ?- phrase(e(T),"not((2+3)=/=5))").
! Resource error: insufficient memory
```

**expected answer**

```
 | ?- phrase(e(T),"not((2+3)=/=5))").
    error 13 ')'
 | ?- phrase(e(T),"(2+3)=>>5))").
    error 7 '>'
```

Comment: Please always include a usable **example query**, the system's current answer, and the **expected answer**.

Comment: I've coded the @false suggestion (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13143803/874024)), as a DCG extension, via term_expansion,  but I'm using SWi-Prolog. Are you interested in alpha testing it in SICSTUS Prolog ?

Comment: @CapelliC which example I tested ?

Comment: forget it, in SICSTUS the interface dcg_translate_rule/2 is missing...

Answer (score 4):

You could try to bottom parse bottom up.

This is the processor:

```
:- op(150, xfx, ---> ).

parse(Phrase) -->
    leaf(SubPhrase),
    lc(SubPhrase, Phrase).

leaf(Cat) --> [Word], {word(Word,Cat)}.
leaf(Phrase) --> {Phrase ---> []}.

lc(Phrase, Phrase) --> [].

lc(SubPhrase, SuperPhrase) -->
    {Phrase ---> [SubPhrase|Rest]},
    parse_rest(Rest),
    lc(Phrase, SuperPhrase).

parse_rest([]) --> [].
parse_rest([Phrase|Phrases]) -->
    parse(Phrase),
    parse_rest(Phrases).
```

An example of grammar specification (but func seems ill specified, and there is no precedence or associativity specification...)

```
expr(E) ---> [opp, expr(E), clp].
expr(not(E)) ---> [not, opp, expr(E), clp].
expr(impl(L,R)) ---> [expr(L), impl, expr(R)].
expr(ne(L,R)) ---> [expr(L), ne, expr(R)].
expr(mul(L,R)) ---> [expr(L), mul, expr(R)].
expr(add(L,R)) ---> [expr(L), add, expr(R)].
expr(func(L,R)) ---> [func(L), impl, func(R)].
expr(num(N)) ---> [num(N)].

func(f(F, As)) ---> [name(F), args(As)].

args([A|As]) ---> [arg(A), comma, args(As)].
args([A]) ---> [arg(A)].
arg(E) ---> [expr(E)].


word(N, name(N)) :- atom(N).
word(N, num(N)) :- integer(N).
word(=>, impl).
word('(', opp).
word(')', clp).
word(*, mul).
word(+, add).
word(not, not).
word(=/=, ne).
word(',', comma).
```

an example run

```
?- phrase(parse(E), [not,'(',2,+,2,*,3,')']).
E = func(f(not, [mul(add(num(2), num(2)), num(3))])) ;
E = func(f(not, [add(num(2), mul(num(2), num(3)))])) ;
E = expr(not(mul(add(num(2), num(2)), num(3)))) ;
E = arg(not(mul(add(num(2), num(2)), num(3)))) ;
E = args([not(mul(add(num(2), num(2)), num(3)))]) ;
E = expr(not(add(num(2), mul(num(2), num(3))))) ;
E = arg(not(add(num(2), mul(num(2), num(3))))) ;
E = args([not(add(num(2), mul(num(2), num(3))))]) ;
false.
```

but maybe this is no so useful for your task...

Comment: thnks, I think it is similar to [LR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) but can you pls add a brief explanation (lc,leaf) or  the `grammar` towards  first example in order to promote understanding

Comment: it's a so called [left corner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_corner_parser) parsing. Follow the link from wikipedia page to get more explanations

Answer (score 2):

You didn't remove the left recursion at all.  You merely replaced direct recursion with indirect; the parsing rules still don't terminate.

You have to start each grammar rule with something that resolves to a distinct, finite set of terminal symbols.  You can use non-terminals, but each must resolve to such a set (no buried left recursion).  The rules in your original grammar that fit this requirement are E1 (left paren), E2 (not) and Func (Ter ... assuming *that* has no left-recursion).

Yes, this requires some uncomfortable changes in your grammar at points.  Turning one rule into three (or six) and creating new non-terminals is a chore.  However, some parsing methods require this.

Have you yet learned how to turn BNF into GNF (Greibach normal form)?  That's a little overkill, but it works quite well.  GNF *requires* that each rules right-hand side begin with a terminal symbol.  I found you a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2ytvL-gegU) lecture and a [PowerPoint](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~rus/cfg3.pdf) presentation on the process.

Does this get you moving?

Comment: thank you to answer me, but is there a general strategy to avoid these types of problems with closest example to the grammar above?

Comment: Yes: see my update with two links.  Then we should delete these comments.

Comment: in [PPT](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~rus/cfg3.pdf) i found an algo to convert CFG to GNF , is there an auto converter CFGrammar to GNF like `Parsing emulator`

Comment: I know that there are plenty of converters, because it's a common programming assignment in graduate foundations classes.  However, I don't know specifically where to find one published.  You might try searching, especially on GitHub.